# Как сделать несколько вариантов транслитерации в Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Как добавить в скрипт возможность несколько вариантов транслитерации для символов ? 
Как пример, если буква 'И' идёт после 'Ь' и 'Ъ' то должна прописываться "YI", а не "I". А в остальных случаях 'И' прописывалась как 'I'.

```
function global:TranslitToLAT
{
param([string]$inString)
$Translit_To_LAT = @{
[char]'а' = "a"
[char]'А' = "a"
[char]'б' = "b"
[char]'Б' = "b"
[char]'в' = "v"
[char]'В' = "v"
[char]'г' = "g"
[char]'Г' = "g"
[char]'д' = "d"
[char]'Д' = "d"
[char]'е' = "e"
[char]'Е' = "e"
[char]'ё' = "e"
[char]'Ё' = "e"
[char]'ж' = "zh"
[char]'Ж' = "zh"
[char]'з' = "z"
[char]'З' = "z"
[char]'и' = "i"
[char]'И' = "i"
[char]'й' = "i"
[char]'Й' = "i"
[char]'к' = "k"
[char]'К' = "k"
[char]'л' = "l"
[char]'Л' = "l"
[char]'м' = "m"
[char]'М' = "m"
[char]'н' = "n"
[char]'Н' = "n"
[char]'о' = "o"
[char]'О' = "o"
[char]'п' = "p"
[char]'П' = "p"
[char]'р' = "r"
[char]'Р' = "r"
[char]'с' = "s"
[char]'С' = "s"
[char]'т' = "t"
[char]'Т' = "t"
[char]'у' = "u"
[char]'У' = "u"
[char]'ф' = "f"
[char]'Ф' = "f"
[char]'х' = "kh"
[char]'Х' = "kh"
[char]'ц' = "tc"
[char]'Ц' = "tc"
[char]'ч' = "ch"
[char]'Ч' = "ch"
[char]'ш' = "sh"
[char]'Ш' = "sh"
[char]'щ' = "shch"
[char]'Щ' = "shch"
[char]'ъ' = "" # "``"
[char]'Ъ' = "" # "``"
[char]'ы' = "y" # "y`"
[char]'Ы' = "y" # "Y`"
[char]'ь' = "" # "`"
[char]'Ь' = "" # "`"
[char]'э' = "e" # "e`"
[char]'Э' = "e" # "E`"
[char]'ю' = "iu"
[char]'Ю' = "iu"
[char]'я' = "ia"
[char]'Я' = "ia"
[char]' ' = "_"
}
$outChars=""
foreach ($c in $inChars = $inString.ToCharArray())
{
if ($Translit_To_LAT[$c] -cne $Null )
{$outChars += $Translit_To_LAT[$c]}
else
{$outChars += $c}
}
Write-Output $outChars
}

$text = Read-Host "Введите текст"
$log = TranslitToLAT $text
$log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
#requires -version 6
using namespace System.Linq

function ConvertTo-Translit {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]$InputString
  )

  begin {
    $latin = ( # массив транслитер ('ъ' и 'ь' представлены символом 'j')
      [Object[]][Char[]]'abvgde' + 'zh' +
      [Object[]][Char[]]'ziiklmnoprstuf' + 'kh' + 'ts' + 'ch' + ,'sh' * 2 +
      [Object[]][Char[]]'jyje' + 'yu' + 'ya' + 'yo'
    )
    $trans = [Linq.Enumerable]::Zip([Char[]]('а'..'я' + 'ё'), [String[]]$latin,
      [Func[Char, String, Object]]{"$($args[0]) = $($args[1])"}
    ) | ConvertFrom-StringData
  }
  process {}
  end {
    -join $(for ($i, $arr = 0, [Char[]]$InputString; $i -lt $arr.Length; $i++) {
      $c = $arr[$i] # текущий символ строки
      $x = $trans.$c # потенциальный символ замены

      if (![Char]::IsLetter($c) -or $c -match '[a-z]') {
        $c # на случай, если символ в строке не является буквой
        continue # или сомволом латинского алфавита
      }

      if ([Char]::IsUpper($c)) {
        "$([Char]::ToUpper($x[0]))$($x[1])" # если буква заглавная
        continue
      }

      if ($x -eq 'j' -and [Char]::IswhiteSpace($arr[$i + 1])) {
        "'" # слово заканчивается на мягкий знак
        continue
      }

      $x
    }) # for
  }
}
```

Тесты:

```
'И Ленин такой молодой, и юный октябрь впереди!' | ConvertTo-Translit
ConvertTo-Translit 'Ёлка, ёжик'
ConvertTo-Translit 'Женщина пекла оладьи, как вдруг LOL! услышала шорох за спиной.'
```

Итог тестов:

```
I Lenin takoi molodoi, i yunyi oktyabr' vperedi!
Yolka, yozhik
Zhenshina pekla oladji, kak vdrug LOL! uslyshala shorokh za spinoi.
```